# I cannot access some openGL functions

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

When I attempt to generate a buffer by executing the `glGenBuffer()` function - no function like that is found.

Some functions are still working, and from what I see most do work, for instance the following code works perfectly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace std;

class Window_Manager
{
public:
    GLFWwindow* window;

    int Create_Window(int width, int height, const char* title) {
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            return -1;
        }

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FOCUSED, GL_TRUE);
        
        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            cout << "Failed to create a window! Aborting early..." << endl;
            Terminate_Window(window);
            return -1;
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height); 
        
        return 1;
    }
    
    void Terminate_Window(GLFWwindow* window) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
        glfwTerminate();
    }
};
```

but this code does not:

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <Engine_Manager.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Shape2D
{
    int VBO;
    int Setting_Up(){
            VBO = glGenBuffer();
            return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you mean [`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml) (plural)?

Comment: What other functions do you feel is not working as intended ? You can use glGetError if so

Comment: The `glGenBuffer()` of the C# helper library you used is a convenience function which uses `glGenBuffers()` internally. Replace your call to glGenBuffer() with:
`glGenBuffers(1, &BVO);` and study the documentation of that function. There are at least a few more cases of this kind.

Comment: @rpress I attempted to use this call, but I still get an error for " identifier "glGenBuffers" is undefined". I don't seem to be able to use glBufferData either.

Comment: You might have to use GLEW in addition to GLFW.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: As rpress suggest you need a wrangler lib like GLEW that will load the GL: funcions above OpenGL 1.0 see [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) , you can load extentions on your own too but that is a lot of code and constants and possibility of errors ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to replacing `glGenBuffer` with `glGenBuffers(1, &VBO)` as rpress mentioned in the comments, OpenGL is a weird library in that you have to load most of the functions dynamically.

The exact details differ from platform to platform. On Windows, for example, you can use [`wglGetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetprocaddress) to get pointers to desired functions.

Rather than do it manually, [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent library for getting OpenGL function pointers easily. [Other options are documented on the OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: OpenGL is not a library. It is a specification. The API is implemented by the graphics driver. Therfore you need a loader.